# I don't want to use ng-repeat in the /item view because it's only showing one item

Tags: angularjs

In my shopping cart, I've stored the items in variables in a service which is injected into my storeCtrl.

I have an itemCtrl and what I need to do is click on an item display by storeCtrl and then open to a new view /item/id and only shows the information from the clicked item.

Currently, I can only display items on /item view by using ng-repeat="items in item", I don't really want to be using ng-repeat

Any ideas how I'd go about this.

Comment: Well, iterate over the items, find the one which has the given ID in the route params, and store this item in the scope.

Comment: Whats wrong with `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Question is really a bit too broad. Are you not able to use the routeParams or stateParams to get the item ID and filter it yourself? Take a look at how it's done in tutorial on angular docs site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean ng-repeat="item in items" instead of ng-repeat="items in item" ?